# Why does this print "Hello World" and not "dlroW olleH"

Tags: c#, arrays, string, reverse

```
namespace Lab1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] LabOne = { "Hello World" };
            for (int i = LabOne.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(LabOne[i]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code in a debugger? How many elements do you think the array has?

Comment: You're not iterating through the characters in a String, you're iterating over a 1-element array of strings. Therefore printing only that 1 string.

Comment: [The debugger is your friend.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)

Comment: string can be treated as array. so if you have  `string LabOne = "Hello World";` then you can point to its characters like `LabOne[i]`.

Comment: As the others have said, put a break point in your application and look at the value for your `int i`. It should have a value of `1`, because there is only 1 element in your `string[]`, which is the complete string "Hello World". So it only loops once and access the first (coincidentally, the last) item in that array, which is "Hello World". Search around for how to  loop over each character in a string.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question.

```
        string str = "hello World!";          
        char[] a = str.ToArray();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = str.Length -1 ; i > 0; i--)
        {
            builder.Append(a[i]);                
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, you have an array of strings and you are printing each element from back to front of the array. However, you only have one element in the array: the string "Hello World." So the back IS the front. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
namespace Lab1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string LabOne = "Hello World";
            for (int i = LabOne.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(LabOne.[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `ElementAt` here.  You should be using the indexer.  You've just turned an O(n) operation into an O(n^2) operation needlessly.

Comment: Evan, this also prints "Hello World"